# Update Claims after user login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

Is it possible to update claims after user login? I have frontend and admin panel in my site, basically I'm using `claims` to achieve this. If a user is logged in as `Susan` in frontend, I did something like this in my code :

```
var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Id", this.UserName));
... //other claims here
```

So when user finally login on admin panel (when still logged on in frontend), I just want to add more claims for example :

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("BackEndId", this.UserName));
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: what's wrong with using the line of code that you posted as an example?

Answer (score 5):

To be able to read the claim on a cookie you need to sign user our and sign them back in again during the same request:

```
idenityt.AddClaim(new Claim("myClaimType", "myClaimValue"));

var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, idenityt);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Add function to ApplicationSignInManager class in Identity.Config.cs

```
    public override Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent, bool rememberBrowser)
     {
                var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                   new Claim("Id", this.UserName),
                   new Claim("BackEndId", this.UserName)
                };
                this.AuthenticationManager.User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
                return base.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, rememberBrowser);
    }
```

> You can use this code to access claims.

```
private ClaimsPrincipal GetCurrentUser()
        {
            var context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
            if (context == null)
                return null;

            if (context.Authentication == null || context.Authentication.User == null)
                return null;

            return context.Authentication.User;
        }


private string GetUserId()
        {
            var user = GetCurrentUser();
            if (user == null)
                return null;

            var claim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == "Id");
            if (claim == null)
                return null;

            return claim.Value;
        }


 private string GetBackEndId()
            {
                var user = GetCurrentUser();
                if (user == null)
                    return null;

                var claim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == "BackEndId");
                if (claim == null)
                    return null;

                return claim.Value;
            }
```